# Does a half-diagonal of a rectangle have a mathematical name?

Tags: terminology

Your *simplest* math question of the day---but I really want to know!

Is there a name for the half-diagonal of a rectangle?

[image]

Comment: Half diagonal of the rectangle? [No, in earnest: Why invent special names if a short, simple description is available?]

Comment: "radius of the circumscribed circle"?

Comment: @vonbrand--agreed, simple is best and half-diagonal is just fine with me. I'm using this measurement in collision tests that I'm working on, and ironically (for me) "circumradius" conjurs in my mind an outward-looking measurement where half-diagonal conjurs and internal measurement. If it were a different word, I might think otherwise. How about that--"feelings" in math!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For regular polygons (i.e. if this were a square) this would be called the ["radius" or "circumradius"](http://www.mathopenref.com/polygonradius.html).  Likewise for regular polygons, the distance from the center to a center of a side is called the ["apothem" or "inradius"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apothem).

**Circumradius** is an appropriate name for rectangles as well, because it is possible to inscribe any rectangle in a circle, and the segment you describe is a radius of that circle.