# Does a half-square have a name?

Tags: terminology

By a half-square I mean a rectangle which has the dimensions $ a \times 2a $ (as opposed to a square which has the dimensions $ 2a \times 2a $)

Comment: Half-square looks good to me ;p.

Comment: "Rectangle"  :p ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Or double-square.

Comment: @mathbeing  -  [half-diagonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315175/does-a-half-diagonal-of-a-rectangle-have-a-mathematical-name?) looked good to me too.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it is good to know the technical name, and I understand your point. However, what I was trying to say with my above comment is that even if you don't use the real name in whatever you need to write, it suffices to specify what you're meaning by _half-square_ and then use it. If you write a good paper with it you might even spread the terminology, given that the current one is not so established.

Comment: @mathbeing - sure, but since English is not my native language, and I never read a lot of technical literature, I wanted to play safe.

Comment: @Gallifreian - Half-square is good as far as the area goes, but I'd avoid "half-diagonal", since the ratio of diagonals in your example is square root of 8 to square root of 5.

Comment: @EdwardPorcella By half-diagonal he means the line segment from the center of a rectangle to its corner.